Xero HMACSHA256 not validating
I am trying to validate against the Xero webhook using C# Azure Function and Power Automate where you hash the body and secret key into base64 and compare against the header x-xero-signature.
They purposely send incorrect x-xero-signature to check your implementation. I have received 3 Posts in a row however none match.
To endeavour to troubleshoot I have used online generator as below and from all 3 none match in the generator or through my function App.
I had concerns that my code was getting the body wrong however is there anything wrong with the way I am trying to manually check for a match or my code?
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace xeroHash
{
    public static class XeroWebHook
    {
        // private static readonly string WebhookSigningKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("XeroWebhookSigningKey");
        private const string WebhookSigningKey = "pwEz4X1A231xPQyKDPIOtIrI9FLhHJ+RHksjdurytsfkL4sNBG4gdmeBa3alD6qHIAGoZX41ay0yp6+lqM8rGQ==";

        [FunctionName("Xerowebhook")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("Processing webhook validation request.");

            // Get x-xero-signature header from request
            var xeroSignature = req.Headers["x-xero-signature"].FirstOrDefault();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(xeroSignature))
            {
                log.LogWarning("Missing Xero signature header.");
                return new UnauthorizedResult();
            }

            // Read the request body (payload)
            string requestBody;
            using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(req.Body))
            {
                requestBody = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
            }

            // Validate the HMACSHA256 signature
            if (!IsSignatureValid(requestBody, xeroSignature, WebhookSigningKey))
            {
                log.LogWarning("Invalid signature.");
                return new UnauthorizedResult();
            }

            // Signature is valid
            log.LogInformation("Signature is valid.");
            return new OkResult();
        }

        // Method to validate the HMACSHA256 signature
        private static bool IsSignatureValid(string payload, string signature, string secret)
        {
            // Decode the base64 secret key
            byte[] keyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(secret);

            // Create HMACSHA256 using the secret key
            using (var hmac = new HMACSHA256(keyBytes))
            {
                // Compute the HMAC hash
                byte[] hash = hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload));

                // Convert the computed hash to base64
                string computedSignature = Convert.ToBase64String(hash);

                // Compare the provided signature with the computed one
                return computedSignature.Equals(signature, StringComparison.InvariantCulture);
            }
        }
    }
}


